# solving modulus equation using triangle inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Determine the values of $x$ satisfying the equality $|3x^2-5|-|2x^2+3|=|x^2-8|$

I can see that it is written in the form $|x|-|y|=|x-y|$
which is true when $x$ and $y$ are of different signs so $xy\le0$ but that does not give the correct answer.

Please tell what am i doing wrong and what is the correct method to solve these kind of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong about when the equality $|x|-|y|=|x-y|$ holds. It holds when (and only when) of of these conditions holds:

- $x\geqslant y\geqslant0$;
- $x\leqslant y\leqslant0$.

I shall now use this to solve your problem. The equality holds if and only if$$3x^2-5\geqslant2x^2+3\geqslant0\text{ or }3x^2-5\leqslant2x^2+3\leqslant0.$$The secons possibility cannot take place, of course. On the other hand\begin{align}3x^2-5\geqslant2x^2+3&\iff x^2\geqslant8\\&\iff x\geqslant\sqrt8\vee x\leqslant-\sqrt8.\end{align}

Comment: so $x$ and $y$ should be of same sign, which implies $xy>0$

Comment: @Gem Yes, of course. Otherwise $|x-y|>\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|\geqslant|x|-|y|$.

Comment: but xy>0 is not giving the correct answer

Comment: @Gem The solution is $x\geqslant\sqrt8\vee x\leqslant-\sqrt8$. Do you agree?

Comment: yes but how do you get it by solving $(3x^2−5)*(2x^2+3)>0$

Comment: @Gem Please read again my answer. I did *not* just write that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. I wrote that $x\geqslant y\geqslant0$ or $x\leqslant y\leqslant0$. That's a stronger statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63931/discussion-between-gem-and-jose-carlos-santos).